# Empire Leftovers

Tags: riddle, limerick

Everyone uses me to climb higher
Some use me to put out fires
Say, something's fishy?
Then something is a-me!
Me, the leftover from an Empire

What am I?

Comment: I think that it is an obvious riddle despite its brevity, but if it takes a while I do have a hint ready. And yes, I realize that the limerick pacing isn't perfect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Foot

Everyone uses me to climb higher

> Usually climbing involves hands and **feet**

Some use me to put out fires

> You can stamp out a small fire with your foot, e.g, crushing a cigarette

Say, something's fishy?

> Possibly referring to the [Red Garra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_garra) foot treatment.

Then something is a-me!

> The game is a**foot**!

Me, the leftover from an Empire

> **Edit:** The foot is a imperial unit of linear measurement, leftover from the British Empire.
>  **Original:** The southern part of Italy is often described as shaped like a boot so maybe the leftover part of the Roman Empire could be described as the "foot".

Comment: Foot is correct. I like the reasoning for the fishy line, I meant it just as a tie-in to the next line. Try again with the Empire line and I'll give you the check.

Comment: @kanoo, Of course, thank you. I've edited now with a better description for the last hint.

Answer (score 1):

I is (or you are)

> a letter.

Everyone uses me to climb higher

> which is a ladder.

Some use me to put out fires

> which is lather.

Say, something's fishy?

> which might be leather.

Then something is a-me!

> not sure yet - might be alerter.

Me, the leftover from an Empire

> which are or which is the latter.